# How to use rangeslider.js in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-4, rangeslider

I want to let the user input data via a slider. I've found [rangeslider.js](http://rangeslider.js.org/)

How can I include this to my railsproject?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [bower](https://bower.io). You will find a good explanation [here](http://dotwell.io/taking-advantage-of-bower-in-your-rails-4-app/).

Then just install the package with the command `bower install --save rangeslider.js`.

At last, include *rangeslider.min.js* to your *application.js*.

---

*A simpler, but hard-to-maintain solution*

1. Move **rangeslider.min.js** to *app/assets/javascripts* and **rangeslider.css** to *app/assets/stylesheets*.
2. Add this line `//= require "rangeslider.min.js"` to application.js.
3. Test it.

---

You can also use a cdn:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/rangeslider.js

Good luck!

Comment: I added a simpler solution

Comment: Do I need to to something else, because nothing is is happening